# arguments to printf and g_print - many syntax ,same result

Tags: c, gtk

i saw the following kind of code :
`g_print("%s\n",_("foo"));`

i haven't seen this style of passing arguments to print function ,but then i tried these :
`g_print("%s\n","foo");
 g_print("%s\n",("foo"));`

then i thought had something to do with gtk(i'm fairly new to it) , but then i tried the same thing with printf :

`printf("%s\n",_("foo"));
 printf("%s\n","foo");
 printf("%s\n",("foo"));`

and all the above do the same thing : print foo to stdout . So my question is does passing the argument as "foo" , _("foo") ,or ("foo") make any difference at all , or is any one syntactic sugar
for the others,both in the case of printf , as well as g_print ?

sorry if this turns out to be a duplicate question ,but i couldn't seem to put my finger on what i should have searched for exactly in the first place .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably seeing some sort of `gettext` macro, such as the one described by the [glib docs](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/unstable/glib-I18N.html#gettext-macro). A common source for these is including `glib/gi18n.h` directly or (most likely) indirectly.

> Marks a string for translation, gets replaced with the translated
>   string at runtime.

[That header file](http://web.mit.edu/barnowl/include/glib-2.0/glib/gi18n.h) contains a few in this vein:

```
#define  _(String) gettext (String)
```

Answer (score 4):

The `_()` is actually a C macro defined as:

`#define _(x) some_func(x)`

Don't confuse it with `("foo")` or `"foo"`. Both of these are same and are just C strings.